# how to implement multiple ifelse in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, numpy-ndarray

I have an array like this and need to replace every 1 with 2, every 3 with 4, every 4 with 1. Is there a way to do this just with np and not loops?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2)
arr=np.random.randint(1,5,(3,3),int)
arr

array([[1, 4, 2],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 1]])
```

If I use array mask sequentially, it doesn't give the expected outcome:

```
array([[2, 1, 2], 
       [2, 4, 1],
       [4, 1, 2]])
```

It is based on a conditional logic and not maths formula

Comment: I would use a separate mask for each replacement. You should be careful about the order of the assignments. If you still need help, please show the code that you tried.

Comment: Better yet, create the masks from the original array rather than after each modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array values don't necessarely range between 1 and 4 you can use `np.select`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(1,5, (3,3))


condlist = [np.logical_or(a==1, a==2),  a==3, a==4]
choicelist= [2, 4, 1]
b = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

which does not care about the order of the conditions

Answer (score 2):

Here's one with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for performance efficiency -

```
def map_values(arr, old_val, new_val):
    sidx = old_val.argsort()
    idx = np.searchsorted(old_val,arr,sorter=sidx)
    return np.where(old_val[idx]==arr, new_val[sidx[idx]], arr)
```

Sample run -

```
In [40]: arr
Out[40]: 
array([[1, 4, 2],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 1]])

In [41]: old_val = np.array([1,3,4])
    ...: new_val = np.array([2,4,1])

In [42]: map_values(arr, old_val, new_val)
Out[42]: 
array([[2, 1, 2],
       [2, 4, 1],
       [4, 1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do this with a lambda function and [`np.vectorize()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2)
arr=np.random.randint(1,5,(3,3),int)

f = lambda x: x%4 + 1 if x in [1,3,4] else x
vfunc = np.vectorize(f)
```

Usage:

```
>>> vfunc(arr)
array([[2, 1, 2],
       [2, 4, 1],
       [4, 1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about the order of assignments. For example, if you do

```
arr[arr == 4] = 1
arr[arr == 1] = 2
```

Now all of the elements that were originally `4` will be `2`, not `1` as you intend.

One solution is to carefully craft the order of assignments:

```
arr[arr == 1] = 2
arr[arr == 4] = 1
```

However, this is very brittle and will fall apart as you introduce more of them. It would be better to create the masks up front from the original array:

```
ones = arr == 1
fours = arr == 4
arr[ones] = 2
arr[fours] = 1
```

Now the order of the assignments won't matter because the masks are determined before modifying the array.

Answer (score 0):

You want `arr % 4 + 1`, except in the case of 2, which stays the same. So use np.where to find all the 2s. Then do `arr % 4 + 1`, then reset all the 2s.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2)
arr=np.random.randint(1,5,(3,3),int)

twos = np.where(arr == 2)
arr = arr % 4 + 1
arr[twos] = 2
print(arr)
```